# Question regarding exterior derivative in local formulation.

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Let $(U,\varphi)$ be a chart of a smooth manifold $M$, and let $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$, where $\Omega^k(M)$ is the $C^{\infty}(M)$ module of differential k-forms on $M$.

We write $\omega|_U = \sum_{I} \omega_{I} dx^{I}$ where $I$ is a multi-index such that $i_1 < \ldots < i_k$.

Then we have $d\omega|_U = \sum_{I}d\omega_I \wedge dx^I$.

In the proof, there is a step where this happens $$d\omega_I \wedge dx^I = \sum_{i_0 = 1}^{n} \partial_{i_0} \omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} dx^{i_0} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^{i_n}$$ Can someone explain what happens here?

Where does the part $$\sum_{i < j} (-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j], \ldots,\hat{X_i}, \ldots,\hat{X_j},\ldots,X_k)$$ disappear (this is one term in the coordinate-independent definition of the exterior derivative)?

I know that, for the Lie-bracket $[-,-]$, and coordinate-vector fields $\partial_i$ with respect to a chart $(U,\varphi = (x^1,\ldots,x^n))$, we have $$[\partial_i,\partial_j] = 0$$ so the first argument in $\omega$ (in the local formulation with respect to a chart) will be $0$, but does this necessarily mean that it is identically zero?

Well, to maybe answer my own question, maybe it is the case: $$\omega(0,\partial_{i_0},\ldots,\hat{\partial_{i_i}}, \ldots,\hat{\partial_{i_j}},\ldots,\partial_{i_k}) = \omega(0\partial_{i_0}+\ldots+0\partial_{i_k},\partial_{i_0},\ldots,\hat{\partial_{i_i}}, \ldots,\hat{\partial_{i_j}},\ldots,\partial_{i_k}) = \sum_{k = i_0}^{i_k} 0 \cdot \omega(\partial_k,\partial_{i_0},\ldots,\partial_{i_k}) = 0$$

Is my reasoning correct?

Edit: To be more explicit, part of my thinking here was trying to connect the coordinate-dependent definition with the coordinate-independent definition, where the coordinate-independent definition for    $$d:\Omega^k(M) \to \Omega^{k+1}(M)$$ is defined by $$d\omega(X_0,\ldots,X_k) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(-1)^j X_j(\omega(X_0,\ldots,\hat{X_j},\ldots,X_k)+\sum_{i < j} (-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i,X_j],\ldots,\hat{X_i},\ldots,\hat{X_j},\ldots,X_k)$$

where, for an argument $a$, $\hat{a}$ means removing that argument.

Comment: You have not included the actual definition you're using. Although I can certainly guess, your question is not clear.

Comment: Which definition? Do you mean the definition for the coordinate-invariant description of the exterior derivative?

Comment: The step you're asking about has nothing to do with Lie brackets, so I can only surmise that you're working with the intrinsic definition, yes. Didier's answer uses only the formula for $d(f\alpha)$. So, yes, I'm confused.

Comment: The coordinate-independent definition of the exterior derivative has a Lie-bracket in one of it´s arguments for the differential k-form.

I was trying to connect the coordinate-independent definition to the coordinate-dependent definition.

Comment: That's what I thought, but since you didn't write out the explicit definition, it's hard to read your mind.  So, yes, using the coordinate vector fields $\partial_i$, the bracket term disappears. What happened to the other terms?

Comment: I´ve edited the question. Yes. I am not sure what you mean with "what happened to the other terms"?

I define $$\omega_I = \omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} = \omega(\partial_{i_1},\ldots,\partial_{i_k})$$

where $\partial_i$ is the coordinate-vector field that sends point in a smooth manifold $M$, to $T_pM$, i.e. $p \mapsto \partial_i|_p \in T_pM$.

Comment: Well, actually, I see now that I should change this.

Comment: It is updated now Ted, I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a function and $\alpha$ is a differential form, then
$$
d(f\alpha) = df \wedge \alpha + f d\alpha.
$$
Applying this to $f = \omega_I$ and $\alpha = dx^I$, and noticing that $d(dx^I) = 0$, yields
$$
d(\omega_I dx^I) = d\omega_I \wedge dx^I.
$$
The result now follows by writing everything in coordinates.
In particular, $d\omega_I=\sum_{i_0=1}^n (\partial_{i_0} \omega_I) dx^{i_0}$, so that one has
$$
d(\omega_I dx^I) = \sum_{i_0 = 1}^n \partial_{i_0}\omega_I dx^{i_0}\wedge dx^I.
$$
Since the multi-index $I$ is given by $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$, we have $\omega_I=\omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ and $dx^I = dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}$.
Hence,
$$
d(\omega_I dx^I) = \sum_{i_0=1}^n \partial_{i_0} \omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} dx^{i_0}\wedge dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k}.
$$

Comment: Ehm, by "f is a function" I suppose you mean that $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, i.e. $f$ is a smooth function from a smooth manifold $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a $0$-form, and $\alpha$ is a differential $k$-form.  But then, the formula is $$d(f\alpha) = df \wedge \alpha-f \wedge d\alpha.$$

More generally we have $\omega \in \Omega^k(M), \eta \in \Omega^{\ell}(M)$ then $$d(\omega \wedge \eta) = d\omega \wedge \eta+(-1)^k\omega \wedge d\eta.$$

(And thanks for the quick answer)

Comment: @Ben123 Yes, by function, I mean "smooth function", or "0-form". But last time I checked, $(-1)^0 = 1$ , not $-1$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I will amend that bit.

Comment: (To late to edit). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Ben123 Yes, there is a very simple reason.  If $f$ is a "0-form" and $\alpha$ is any differential form, $f\wedge \alpha$ is tautologically equal to $f \alpha$ in the sense of pointwise multiplication by a function

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing now. Thanks a lot. This was helpful :)

Comment: @Ben123 As a side note, the wedge product is built in order to extend the multiplication by functions as an algebraic product to the whole exterior algebra. In that sense, $f\wedge \alpha = f\alpha$ is **a definition**, not a property. Some textbooks define everything in coordinates as if it was out of the blue, but really, there are reasons for these apparently *ad-hoc* definitions, and the above equality if one of them.

Comment: I suppose it should be pretty easy to complete the proof from what you´ve written then, I mean $$d(\omega|_U) = d(\sum_{I} \omega_I dx^I ) = \sum_{I}d(\omega_I dx^I) = \sum_{I} d\omega_I \wedge dx^I$$ using the relation $$d(\omega_I dx^I) = d\omega_I \wedge dx^I$$?

Comment: @Ben123 Exactly, because the exterior derivative is linear.

Comment: Yes, my thinking is that it is $d$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinear, and viewing $\omega \in C^{\infty}(M)$ the second $=$ in my equation above is allowed.

Comment: @Ben123 $d$ is not $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-linear, but $\Bbb R$-linear.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about $$d\omega: \frak{X}(M) \times \ldots \times \frak{X}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$$

(comment: for some reason, the frak font carries over to other symbols here, I don't know how to avoid it. That is the reason for the frak-style on the font)

Comment: But, yes, I think I understand, you mean that for $\eta,\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$ and $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$d(\alpha\eta+\beta\omega) = \alpha d(\eta)+\beta d(\omega).$$